# How to delete all duplicate occurance of a string after second match found in uipath?

Tags: vb.net, replace, duplicates, uipath

I have a string that contains the following:

Invoice Type|Vanula|Invoice|December| Invoice to be submitted according to Invoice type-priority|2022

I want to keep the first Invoice Type and remove/replace all other instances where Invoice or Invoice type.

The first Invoice Type will always be constant but the rest can be dynamic. Please advise?

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then come back and add the code you've tried and we can help you from there.

Comment: Guessing you're dealing with some delimited data here of some type.  Easiest start point is really to read that into some form typed collection (DataTable, List(Of CustomType)).  Then from there, parsing it however you require should be easy enough

Comment: Thanks, is there a particular regex pattern I can use?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.